# SAML integration with php web application - one confusion

Tags: saml, simplesamlphp

I followed steps listed here to configure simpleSAMLphp as a Service Provider because "the only thing I need is to add SAML authentication support to my website so that users could be authenticated via an SAML identity provider instead of my application's local database".

This is the link from where I followed steps:

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp

Everything works till step 5. simpleSAMLphp web pages open, login through external identity provider works and it comes back to simpleSAMLphp web page.

Now the key goal is step 6 - which is titled as "Integrating authentication with your own application". This is what I need. This step says I need to add code like:

require_once('../../lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');

in my web application's files to secure. As you can see it is accessing class SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple. Since till step 5, simpleSAMLphp was being configured independently (and that works), so how will SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple or other classes of simpleSAMLphp be accessible within my web application? How does that library become accessible to my code? This is not explained in that documentation in step 6.

Can you help me please?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you found the answer?